# Custom theme selection

Tags: magento2, html, luma-theme

I am new to Magento front end development while creating my custom theme,

I  have created **app\design\frontend\custom\themename** and inside that created my **theme.xml** file.

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
     <title>themename</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
     <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
     <media>
         <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
     </media>
 </theme>`
```

But in **Stores->Configuration->Design->Design** Theme not showing my theme name in dropdown[image]

Comment: Clear your cache

Comment: Please let me know if you are stuck.

Comment: your great man it works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create media folder and inside that folder add your `preview.jpg` file.

Create `registration.php` file inside theme,

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
                \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
                'frontend/custom/themename',
                __DIR__
);
```

Run command,

**`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check your theme inside

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

Now check in your backend,
[image]

Clear cache and var folder content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create **registration.php** to **register your theme**.

Registration.php **file code** :

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
                \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
                'frontend/Vendorname/themename',
                __DIR__
);
```

After that clear the cache by running **cache:clean** command and check it will show in design configuration setting dropdown

Also from admin click on **Content->Design->Configuration** here you can see your custom theme

For more details refer this link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html